# Direct DOM acces when working with React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I started lately to work with react-redux architecture.
I want to clean some fields after a successful operation.
I know how to do it using the react-redux way but I was wondering:
Would it be considered a bad practice to clean these fields using plain javascript?
I know it affects the time machine, but i dont consider this as a critical state to preserve.

Pros and Cons are welcome and not just a strict answer.

And an example:

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.onChange}/>
```

I update parent's private field with the onChange event. 
I know I can bound the private field to input's value field but since the only need for that is to clear the field I thought perhaps I can avoid it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show an example of what you consider the "react-redux way" to be?

Comment: edit my question. let me know if something else is missing. thanks!

Comment: If you know the React mechanisms available for clearing out the input field but do not want to use them, then why are you using React?

Comment: I appreciate the response. But it is unhelpful and doesn't help me to understand. If it is considered bad practice just mention it. I learned react+redux 2 weeks ago and thus not fimiliar with all of its philosophy and practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing some non-crucial state in your components is not against the rules of Redux. It just makes things less consistent and predictable. In the long run you may regret the little bits of state you have in your component tree.

As far as your example, though, you do not need to reference the DOM to reset the text value. Since you are storing your text value in a private field already, why not store that field in state?

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.onChange} />
```

Then to reset it you can just `setState({text: ""})`.

Comment: isnt setState is against redux rules as state must be immutable? or you gave this example as a better approach than direct dom access?

Comment: Using Redux doesn't mean you should never use `setState`, it just means you aren't using Redux for that piece of state (and since you are already storing state in a private field, you are already not using Redux for that). Redux doesn't dictate that you have to store *all* state in the Redux store. You just have to understand the difference,